# Can I made an Arduino line follower robot without IR sensor?

Tags: arduino

I want to make an Arduino line follower , but I don't have an Ir senson . Can I make it without it , maybe using an Ultrasonic sensor ? And if the asnwer is yes , how ?

Comment: for sure... you can use a camera and a detect the line.... at some point you will need a sensor and an algo behind that to interpret the data and make decisions...

Comment: That's amazing ! But what is an algo ?

Comment: an algorithm I mean :)

Comment: You can build a line following robot using a camera. You will need to use some computer vision in your algorithm, which makes it more complex. You can try to do this virtually here: https://roboton.io/challenge/camera-set

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make without IR-sensor. Also you can use colour identification sensor to add more accurecy.
In the following links you can find examples 
**Line Following Robot Using Smartphone's Camera**
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/theSTEMpedia/line-following-robot-using-smartphone-s-camera-c16050 
 
**Lane Following Robot using OpenCV** 
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Aasai/lane-following-robot-using-opencv-da3d45
 NOTE:-
I recomend you to use robot simulator software like **[Webots](https://cyberbotics.com/)**  to get more brainstorming ideas.